# Modified SVG in Illustrator causing invertion of fill

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg

I have opened a simple svg icon in Illustrator and added a filled rectangle to it. When I save and open the result in chrome, for example, it looks fine. However if I open it in Fontello, it breaks. The area where the rectangle overlaps the original image is inverted:

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to prevent this in illustrator.

Comment: Looks like the site probably expects a single combined path. Try uniting the shapes or use the shapebuilder tool.

Comment: @BillyKerr Thanks. That was what I needed. This issue comes up a lot for (unskilled) users of Fontello like myself.

Comment: Oh, great! Glad that worked for you.